# How to properly remap `<del>` to `<esc>` in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm a happy owner of a [TypeMatrix](http://www.typematrix.com/) 2030, as well as a happy vim user. On this keyboard the `<del>` have a central place, while the `<esc>` is the top-left key as usual. So I would like to remap my `<del>` key to `<esc>`. So far I added this lines to my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <del> <esc>
nnoremap <del> <esc>
inoremap <del> <esc>
vnoremap <del> <esc>
xnoremap <del> <esc>
snoremap <del> <esc>
cnoremap <del> <esc>
onoremap <del> <esc>
```

It almost works fine, except in the command-line mode : entering `:cmd<del>` will launch the help as would `:cmd<enter>`, while `:cmd<esc>` will erase the line and return to normal mode.

Here is the output for `:verbose cnoremap <Del>`:

```
c  <Del>       * <Esc>>    
    Last changed in ~/.config/vim/vimrc
```

Output for others modes give a similar result, with the strange double chevron `>>`, but works fine (typing  while in insert mode will switch to normal mode).

Comment: Note: `noremap` does the same work as the combination of `nnoremap`, `vnoremap`, and `onoremap`. Likewise, `noremap!` does the work of `inoremap` plus `cnoremap`; and `vnoremap` does the work of `xnoremap` plus `snoremap`. If you're not listing all of them just to be super-clear about what you're doing, you could combine them into only three map commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this behavior is due to what's described under `:help c_Esc` (read "macros" as "mappings"; they're closely related):

> ```
>   <Esc>   When typed and 'x' not present in 'cpoptions', quit
>           Command-line mode without executing.  In macros or when 'x'
>           present in 'cpoptions', start entered command.
> ```

You can work around this by using `<C-c>` instead:

```
:cnoremap <del> <C-c>
```